# Pick image form React Carousel and push it into a new variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have a React Carousel with 4 images for example.

```
import React from 'react'
import { FacebookShareButton } from "react-share";

import img1 from './images/kitten/200.jpg'
import img2 from './images/kitten/201.jpg'
import img3 from './images/kitten/202.jpg'
import img4 from './images/kitten/203.jpg'

const imageList = [img1, img2, img3, img4]

 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.selected = "";
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
      <Carousel>
         {imageList.map((each) => (
         <img src{each} />
         ))}
      </Carousel>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I would like to pick one image from the slider

And push it in new variable defined above called `this.selected`

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using ``state``.

Comment: @Score-6 thank you for the suggestion, a good idea but how to get the image from the Carousel to the state for example? it would be very helpful if you can share an example

Comment: ``this.setState()``

Comment: Where should I place it? inside the <img onClick> or create arrow function outside the render and setState there?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your suggestions, is this what you want?

```
import React from 'react'
import { FacebookShareButton } from "react-share";

import img1 from './images/kitten/200.jpg'
import img2 from './images/kitten/201.jpg'
import img3 from './images/kitten/202.jpg'
import img4 from './images/kitten/203.jpg'

const imageList = [img1, img2, img3, img4]
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {selected: ""};
 }
 pickFromCarousel(image) {
     this.setState({selected: image});
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
      <Carousel>
         {imageList.map((each) => (
         <img onClick={() => this.pickFromCarousel(each)} src={each} />
         ))}
      </Carousel>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

using `state`.

What I am doing is adding a `selected` to `state` in the constructor, and, of course, setting it to null first. We add a function called `pickFromCarousel` which says to set `selected` to the image requested. Then, in our `render` function, we use `pickFromCarousel` as our function when the image is clicked, by use of an arrow function. The rest of the code is practically the same as yours.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sara-rln7f?file=/src/App.js it has an error please check attached, may i ask why the function name is addToCarousel where it should be pick from carousel because that is exactly what i want to achive

Comment: @Dev01 because your post is confusing.

Comment: I have already stated that in the Title nevermind ? did u check the link ?

Comment: yes. of course I did. I am trying to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I appreciate it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sara-rln7f?file=/src/App.js this is working now. The problem was we were passing the function call to the image onClick, instead, it should be onClick={() => this.pickFromCarousel(each)} but there is still a problem the image carousel are rendered twice now ? i don`t know why

Comment: Can you show me a picture? Because I'm stuck at an error that says ``t is undefined``, just right now.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sara-rln7f?file=/src/App.js open this link it is updated, I would like yours as well can u send me please thanks

Comment: Mine is this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sky-vewtq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Also, if you selected any image *other than the first one* there's only one carousel.

Comment: Yes you are right I don`t know why i also faced the same problem when i used the ImagePicker it is better but unfortunately the error "Cannot read property map of undefined" prevent me from using it

Comment: (You can ask that as a separate question; for now please accept my answer)... (click the gray checkmark)

Comment: As said, click the gray checkmark to accept @Dev01

Comment: I would rather wait for a few more days because that is the way it should be if there is no better answer I will accept yours. Thank you